# Applescript: Textedit Password

Tags: macos, passwords, applescript, textedit

I'm new to Applescript. I am stumped on this problem of how to read and write a text file and use the contents as a variable. I have done research on this, but nothing works or makes sense. I want to read a text file, which would contain a word or numbers. The word or numbers, let's say 123, would be assigned to a variable called pass. I need an Applescript to ask the user what the password should be, then make a new text file with the password on it. I also need an Applescript to change the password. The following Applescript will be for changing the password.

```
set theFile to "Users:username:Desktop:pass.txt" as alias
set pass to (read file theFile)
display dialog "Password:" default answer "" with hidden answer
if text returned of result is pass then
    display dialog "New Password:" default answer "" with hidden answer
    display dialog "Again:" default answer "" with hidden answer
    -- code here to change text in pass.txt
    display dialog "Password changed."
end if
```

I just need a starter, or a useful website, or anything that can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with plain Applescript **Standard Additions**. You find the handlers inside the **File Read/Write** section.

```
set theFile to "Users:Username:Desktop:pass.txt" as alias
set pass to (read theFile)
display dialog "Password:" default answer "" with hidden answer
if text returned of result is pass then
    set newPass1 to text returned of (display dialog "New Password:" default answer "" with hidden answer)
    set newPass2 to text returned of (display dialog "Again:" default answer "" with hidden answer)
    -- check the new passwords
    if newPass1 = newPass2 and newPass1 ≠ "" then
        -- open the file
        set pwdFile to open for access theFile with write permission
        -- delete the content
        set eof of pwdFile to 0
        -- write new content
        write newPass1 to pwdFile
        -- close the file
        close access pwdFile
        display dialog "Password changed."
    end if
end if
```

BTW: `read theFile` does not need a file, your alias **theFile** is enough!

BTW: I hope this script is for learning purposes only. I strongly recommend not to handle your user's passwords this way...!

Enjoy, Michael / Hamburg